# HTML5 - pattern won't work properly

Tags: regex, html

I am making a pattern which needs the following:

- 8-10 string length
- 1 number
- 1 latin letter
- 1 special characters

Here is my pattern:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[@#$%^&*()_+]).{8,10}
```

And this my markup:

```
<input pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[@#$%^&*()_+]).{8,10}" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form__input" required title="One latin,One number,One Symbol" />
```

Why it does it not work as I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try this:

```
"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,10}$"
```

Comment: and btw you are looking for regex :) not "design patterns"

Comment: Hey that worked real nice, care to elaborate what ^ and $ is for , also why is this needed [A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&] , do u need to add everything at the end.
Thanks so much.

Comment: ^ means begining,

$ means end,

Comment: you need to add [A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&] because u want to match 8-10 characters from this.
http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html there is a great site with regexes explained and another one to test https://regexr.com/ (however this sometimes doesnt work for me) @PeterGrifison

Comment: Thanks so much kind stranger ,appreciate the knowledge you shared.